# Oracle User Defined String Aggregation function creation issue when run via SQL Script

Tags: oracle

I have a Oracle User Defined Function for String Aggregation

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE StringAggType AS OBJECT 
    (
   theString VARCHAR2(4000),
   STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize
  (sctx IN OUT StringAggType) RETURN NUMBER,
  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT StringAggType , inputValue IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER,
  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN StringAggType, returnValue OUT VARCHAR2, flags IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER,
  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT StringAggType, ctx2 IN StringAggType) RETURN NUMBER
   );
   /

  CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY StringAggType IS
    STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT StringAggType)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
    BEGIN
        sctx := StringAggType(NULL);
        RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
   END;

   MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT StringAggType, inputValue IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN NUMBER IS
   BEGIN
       self.theString := self.theString || ',' || inputValue;
       RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
   END;

   MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN StringAggType, returnValue OUT VARCHAR2, flags IN NUMBER)
   RETURN NUMBER IS
   BEGIN
       returnValue := RTRIM( LTRIM( self.theString, ',' ), ',' );
       RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
   END;

   MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT StringAggType, ctx2 IN StringAggType) 
   RETURN NUMBER IS
   BEGIN
       self.theString := self.theString || ',' || ctx2.theString;
       RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
   END;
   END;
   /

  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION StringAgg(inputString VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
  PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING StringAggType;
  /
```

It compiles perfectly and UDF is created when it is run from SQL Developer IDE but when it is run via a SQL Script with a Java program executing the script, it gives error like:

**ORA-00900 : Inavlid SQL Statement** for lst line it encounters that of

**RETURN ODCIConst.Success;**

Only difference is that I am replacing / with ; for delimiters for SQL Statement execution.
Any ideas why this is happening when run from inside SQL Script ?

Comment: The code you posted is what you run from Java or the one you executed in SQL Developer?

Comment: This is from SQL Developer IDE. Database is Oracle 11g R2.

Comment: The same code runs well in a script; you don't need any change

Comment: @Aleksej I get error when I place it in a .sql script and replace / with ; for allowing execution. I am running the SQL Script via a Java program and it fails at line 18 RETURN ODCIConst.Success;  saying invalid SQL Statement.

Comment: Replacing / with ; will give you extra ;. How do you launch it in java? do you call the sqlplus from java? If so, you don't need to edit this code

Comment: @Aleksej I am using plain JDBC Statement object which takes a sql string and tries to execute it as a sql statement